# Invisible meshes after update

Tags: mesh

Before the 2.8 I hid some meshes and now i cannot unhide them... Here is an image. [image]

Answer (score 0):

In the *Outliner*, click on the key icon to make some other options visible, like *Globally Disable In Viewport*, which may be deactivate for your objects.

[image]